# Some RGB values seem not to be convertable into a Color Object

Tags: java, image, graphics, colors, rgb

I have this kind of method:

```
public void SaveImageOntoObject(String filepath) throws IOException {


      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filepath));
      this.width = image.getWidth();
      this.height = image.getHeight();
      this.ResetPointInformation();
      for (int row = 0; row < width; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < height; col++) {
            this.PointInformation[row][col] = new Color(image.getRGB(col, row));
        }
     }
  }
```

It takes the filepath of an image as input, converts the RPG Value of each pixel into a Color Object and then stores it into the two-dimensional Array PointInformation of the Object the Method was called onto.

**Now to my problem:**

While some pictures like this one:

[image]

Work like a charm, others like this:

[image]

Let me end up with the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:318)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:888)
at Drawing.Object2D.SaveImageOntoObject(Object2D.java:75)** (that's the class whose object's my method works on)
```

Why is that like that? It seems like Java is not able to convert certain RGB values into Colors?

Could you tell me how I can make it work?

Comment: I suspect that code is mixing up rows with columns, and the first image does not fail simply because it is 100x100 (square).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message actually says it: "index out of bounds". It seems, that you confused your coordinates and their bounds.  `getRGB` takes the parameters `x` (range 0 .. `width`) as first, and `y` (range 0 .. `height`) as second.

```
this.width = image.getWidth();
this.height = image.getHeight();

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {        // swapped the ...
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {     // ... bounds
        this.PointInformation[row][col] = new Color(image.getRGB(col, row));
    }
}
```

Your first example has width = height, so that the problem doesn't show.

Comment: You should mention that the method itself takes x as the first parameter: `getRGB(int x, int y)`.